# Identify file type / encoding

Tags: encryption, decode, obfuscation, file-type

I am using a 3rd party software that stores templates for ID cards in a database. I believe the templates are in xml format but are encrypted / encoded / compressed in the database.

Each encoded template has the same header at the beginning of the file:

```
A9 CD AA F5 AE 36 04 2F 04 2A A5 2F CE EF B0 83 C4 97 F7 CA 26 F7 28 ED F8 C3 26 F4 57 D5 CB EA 36 10 F9 9B A6 CE F2 67 6B 47 B9 16 6E A7 41 14 A2 CD 99 88 51 17 67 03 C0 C4 66 18 D6 2A 1F D2 DD 5F 24 83 14 87 96 35 90 B6 70 F1 E6 51 BD 7A AB 41 86 E8 4D F4 E0 B7 D4 0A 22 DA 26 BD 54 D4 DE D1 23 36 BE D8 C8 D9 EC D8 5B 0E 0B 1D BE D8 A3 BD B7 E4 37 40 EB 86 76 85 E5 F7 15 87 EB 47
```

Is there a way of finding out / does any one recognise this file format?

The file may be some kind of archive containing images and xml files.

Sample files uploaded here:

Empty Template: [Here](https://ufile.io/8b59a)

Actual template with image (png format): [Here](https://ufile.io/e2bd6)

Comment: This is called guessing and it mostly a loser's game.   I'd ask the provider.  If you want access to all the data, why don't you just ask the 3rd party tool to export it all?

Comment: @IraBaxter It's called reverse engineering and appears to have been crossposted there as well: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14168/decrypt-decode-decompress-proprietary-file

Comment: @IraBaxter 3rd Party very unhelpful... they dont wanna know. Didnt realise there was a reverse engineering part to stack exchange until I had already posted.

Comment: @barrycarter:Yes, I'm familiar with the term, check my bio.  Generally trying to do this when you have no real knowledge of what the data really is or how it might be encoded, a specific process for tackling it and good tools, and a lot of enthusiasm... usually means you don't get anywhere.   I'm trying to suggest to OP that he should really find another path unless he wants to invest a lot of energy here.  (Yes, he might be lucky and stumble on a answer at RE... that would be a cheap and useful path.  I've usually found that betting on luck isn't lucky.)

Comment: @IraBaxter My immediate suggestion would be to look for headers (like "JFIF" though that's not appropriate here) in the body of the binary. I wonder if there's a program that does that (shouldn't be hard to create one).